# ListView headers flickering while scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have troubles with my ListView. My datatemplate consist of image and 2 textblock. But some images don't have source and therefore not be displayed. I think the reason of flickering is that some items don't have images (only textblocks) and so they have different size. So how I can solve that?

That's my xaml code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="phts" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Name="image" MaxHeight="90" MaxWidth="90" Stretch="Fill" Tag="{Binding Url}"/>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="txt1" Text="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding Url}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="txt2" Text="{Binding Title2}" Tag="{Binding Url}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate">
        <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="0,5,0,5" Tag="{Binding Key}">
            <Border Background="#E0E0E0" 
                    Width="400" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tag="{Binding Group_ID}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Padding="6"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <ListView Background="White"
              Foreground="Black"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource phts}}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

That's my code:

```
public sealed partial class TestPage : Page
{

    public TestPage()
    {
        this.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
        this.InitializeComponent();

        loadContent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void loadContent()
    {
        NewsGroup group1 = new NewsGroup("Test 1");
        NewsGroup group2 = new NewsGroup("Test 2");
        NewsGroup group3 = new NewsGroup("Test 3");
        NewsGroup group4 = new NewsGroup("Test 4");
        NewsGroup group5 = new NewsGroup("Test 5");
        NewsGroup group6 = new NewsGroup("Test 6");

        List<NewsGroup> groups = new List<NewsGroup>(new NewsGroup[] {group1, group2, group3, group4, group5, group6});

        Random rand = new Random();
        foreach(NewsGroup group in groups)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ArticleHeader hdr = new ArticleHeader();

                if (rand.Next() % 5 == 2)
                {
                    hdr.Image = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1885929594/Nomad_watermark_white.jpg";
                }

                hdr.Title = "Short title";
                hdr.Title2 = "Very big title here should be. Bla bla bla bla bla! Bla bla bla? Blablabl blab bla bla lab bbalblablalb blablalbal";

                group.Add(hdr);
            }
        }

        ((CollectionViewSource)Resources["phts"]).Source = groups;
    }
}

public class ArticleHeader
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Title2 { get; set; }
}

public class NewsGroup : List<ArticleHeader>
{
    public NewsGroup(string name)
    {
        Key = name;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string GroupUrl { get; set; }
    public string Group_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use * sizing instead of Auto in ColumnDefinition.

Comment: @Vishal, that doesn't solve problem

Comment: Can you please post images?

Comment: this is just test image. no matter what image is, problem i think is that listviewitems have different content. For example, if there will be no images, flickering would not be happen, or if each listviewitem has images flickering also would not be happen. That's my test images: https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1885929594/Nomad_watermark_white.jpg

Comment: When I change my listview with gridview, problem is disappeared, but gridview places content in different way, that not appropriate for me

Comment: Sorry, I did not clarify. Please post the screenshot of your flickering ListView.

Comment: Why it is not appropriate for you to use gridView? Internal mechanism might be different but you should get identical output.

Comment: Just try to scroll to the end of listview and then try to scroll fast to beginning and you will see, that top header is flickering. I can't make screenshoft of this

Comment: I want to show my content like ListBox, not like a Table. ListView - one column, many rows. GridView - 2 or more columns and rows. Or I can set gridview to place content in one column?

Comment: Yes you can use only 1 column for displaying content in GridView.

Comment: @Vishal, how can I do that?

Comment: Simply use a DataGrid. <DataGrid> <DataGrid.Columns> <DataGridTemplateColumn><DataGridTemplateColumn.........>

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Windows Phone but I use WPF and there I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of problem. Mine happened as I navigated to a new screen, I looked through some of the documentation and blog posts around and found that if I set my opacity to 99% (0.99) in the xaml tag for the list or the entire xaml page it went away. I know this is a very hacky solution, but the original problem in itself made no sense. Try this and let me know if it works. The code above makes no flicker when I deploy it to my device. I'm using a Nokia Lumia 1520 to test with.

Also I would suggest using MVVM Pattern so you can have you logic outside of your UI related code. Would be easier to manage and find problems. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: I tried to chang opacity, but it didn't help me. Here is the video of my current app, where I faced with this trouble. You can see from the beginning, that top header is flickering: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=65A15980B252B4BA!19089&authkey=!AMVH0LPJeOfwcHs&ithint=video%2cmp4

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same behavior in multiple ListViews in my apps.
The only solution (to my knowledge) is to set the Item contents height to a fixed value.

Also:
Working with min-height reduces the flickering, if only few of your items have a varying height.